# i am getting error undefined symbol: __const_udelay?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I tried placing udelay(500); in kernel files and i am getting an error **undefined symbol: __const_udelay** I included linux/delay.h header file.
why i am getting this error ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you turned optimizing off? I have read that this might produce undefined errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a link-time error. Linker could not find where __const_udelay() is implemented. In x86, it could be found in *arch/x86/lib/udelay.c*